# How do I make a calculator that multiplies more than two numbers?

Tags: java

I made a calculator that does multiple things (adding consecutive numbers, adding multiple numbers, etc) but I am having trouble making it so that the calculator can multiply multiple numbers. So far, I've basically copied the code that adds multiple numbers, but I can't figure out how to make it multiply instead of add.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfNumbers {
public static void main(String arg[])
{
int n;
int sum = 0;

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please enter how many numbers you want to add up to: ");
n = s.nextInt();

System.out.println("you entered: " + n + "");
sum = addConsecutiveNumbers(n);

System.out.println("sum of 1 to "+n+" = "+sum);



//following code is sum of any numbers you entered from console
//store the numbers into an array
int num;
int sumOfNums=0;

System.out.print("Please enter how many numbers you want to sum: ");
num=s.nextInt();
System.out.println("you want to sum "+num+" numbers ");

sumOfNums = addNumbers(num);

System.out.println("sum of "+num+" numbers = "+sumOfNums);
}



//Define a method which add consecutive numbers based on user's input and return the sum of the numbers
private static int addConsecutiveNumbers (int number)
{
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
{
sum = sum + i;
}

return sum;

}


//Define a method which add numbers based on user's input and return the sum of the numbers

private static int addNumbers (int num)
{
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int a[] = new int[num];
int sumOfNums = 0;

for(int k = 0; k < num; k++)
{
System.out.println("enter  number  "+(k+1)+":");
a[k] = s.nextInt();

System.out.println("The array of a[" + k + "] = " + a[k]);
}

for(int j = 1;j < num ; j++)
{
sumOfNums += a[j];
}

return sumOfNums; 
}
//below is the part of code that I am having trouble with.

public static int multiplyNumbers(int num)
{
    int Area = 0; 
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a[] = new int[num];
    System.out.println("Please enter how many numbers you want to multiply:");
    num=s.nextInt();
    for(int l = 0; l < num; l++)
    {
    System.out.println("enter  number  "+(l+1)+":");
    a[l] = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The array of a[" + l + "] = " + a[l]);
    }
    return Area;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one thing right away; The way I see your code, the following two lines a redundant:

```
System.out.println("Please enter how many numbers you want to multiply:");
num=s.nextInt();
```

You should have already asked the user how many numbers they want to multiply, because it's passed in as a parameter.  As for your actual problem, take a look at these lines from the `addNumbers()` method:

```
for(int j = 1;j < num ; j++)
{
sumOfNums += a[j];
}
```

All you gotta do is copy that code in right before your return statement (`return Area;`).  You'll need to tweak it a bit so instead of using the `sumOfNums` variable, it uses the `Area` variable, and instead of adding, it multiplies.  This can be done like so:

```
for(int j = 0;j < num ; j++) //j also needs to start at 0, I think you may have made a mistake when writing the summing method
{
Area *= a[j];
}
```

You'll notice there's an issue with this algorithm though (almost didn't catch it myself).  `Area` starts off with a value of 0, so 0 multiplied by any number will always still be 0.  Simple fix; just manually set `Area` to the first value before the loop.  Something like this:

```
Area = a[0];
for(int j = 1; j < num; j++)
{
sumOfNums += a[j];
}
```

Also notice I started the for loop at `j = 1` this time.  This is because I already started `Area` as `a[0]`, so we don't want to multiply that number twice.

Comment: if `num = 0` then `Area = a[0]` will through IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, too, but I didn't want to add unnecessary information.  When you think about it, it doesn't make sense to multiply 0 numbers.  The same is true for negative values of `num`; they will throw a `NegativeArraySizeException`.  If I was writing the program, I would just check these things before I called the method, and then let it throw the exceptions in weird cases.  That way I know when I did something I shouldn't have.  Thanks for pointing it out, though

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store values in an array for multiplication similarly for addition you can directly update the final result

```java
    public static int multiplyNumbers(int num) {
        int Area = 1;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter how many numbers you want to multiply:");
        num = s.nextInt();
        for (int l = 0; l < num; l++) {
            System.out.println("enter  number  " + (l + 1) + ":");
            int temp = s.nextInt();
            Area *= temp;
            System.out.println("The array of a[" + l + "] = " + temp);
        }
        return Area;
    }
```